# Can we extract an interesting question based on this closed and deleted question?

Tags: discussion

I recently come across this question [How come Japanese animation studios never produce anime for international audiences?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24049/how-come-japanese-animation-studios-never-produce-anime-for-international-audien) in the list of deleted questions. It is closed as "unclear what you are asking" and has been deleted by roomba script.

The question body reads:

> Other than their usual Japanese audience, Why have animation studios never made an anime targetted internationally? - i.e. at non Japanese audiences?

I think this question might have interesting answer, from reading the comments:

> Considering Naruto's low rating in Japan, it is clear that the reason it still continues is because the non-japanese market is their intended market. Never produced anime for international audiences? Not really then. –  Sakurai Tomoko Aug 13 at 11:43
>
> There are several targetted at western audiences, but they've mostly failed miserably. [...] –  Toshinou Kyouko Aug 13 at 12:54
>
> @ToshinouKyouko for example, Alexander Senki. Miserable failure, deservedly so. –  Torisuda Aug 13 at 17:38

---

The OP does comment, clarifying (?) their intention:

> @SakuraiTomoko Sorry but thats not the right answer I'II clarify the question,I mean why don't anime studios create an anime with original English language because they creating for English speaking audiences aside from its Japanese audiences? –  Daniel Aug 13 at 11:54

This seems to be another question altogether, *probably* asking *Why anime is not produced with both English dub and Japanese dub?*

---

Does the community think if it's feasible to extract interesting questions out of this deleted question?

<sup>I'm not asking to salvage it, since it may conflict with the intention of the original author of the deleted question.</sup>

Comment: How I interpret the original question: why is there no anime in which a real language other than Japanese is spoken primarily, especially by the main characters (why all these Americans/Asians speak Japanese?) I think this question is good and shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Comment: @Gao The problem is - without a clear wording, the question can take an entirely different direction. Even your interpretation is different from mine, which shows that the original question is unclear. Do feel free to post your question, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think we can actually get at least three potentially interesting questions from this, based on different interpretations of what the OP wanted to know. If the OP had edited to clarify which of these interpretations was correct, the original question could have been reopened, but this particular user has been posting potentially interesting but highly unclear questions for at least two months now, and never comes back to improve them once they're closed.

These are the three questions I think we could get:

> ### How have non-Japanese audiences affected the way the anime industry operates?
>
> Recently, the international reception a movie is likely to get has
>   changed the way Hollywood produces movies, as described in the BBC
>   article ["How the global box office is changing
>   Hollywood"](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20130620-is-china-hollywoods-future).
>   According to the article, Hollywood has changed what kinds of movie it
>   produces, which actors it casts, and in a few cases has even modified
>   scripts, all because of how they think it will play to an
>   international market.
>
> Most anime are produced solely for a Japanese audience. However,
>   Japanese studios must be aware that their creations are being licensed
>   and seen outside of Japan. Has there been any change in the way the
>   industry operates due to international audiences—in general, or
>   in specific cases?

This question should cover what the OP of the original question apparently wanted to know—a Japanese studio producing an anime targeted primarily at a non-Japanese audience would definitely count as a change in the industry. The original question assumes that this has never happened, but I know of at least a few corner cases which may qualify—Alexander Senki, Blood: The Last Vampire, and The Animatrix (depending on whether you consider that anime).

Answers to this question that talk about a specific work should cite interviews with staff, or at least the opinions of respected critics and scholars, as evidence that a particular change occurred because of non-Japanese audiences. For example, a bad answer would be "Cowboy Bebop and Baccano were only made because the studios knew they would end up in front of American audiences." A better answer would cite interviews where the staff discuss their strategy in targeting American audiences.

> ### Has an anime which was unpopular with a Japanese audience ever been sustained by popularity with non-Japanese audiences?
>
> Some anime aren't very successful among the Japanese audience, but
>   find a lot of success once they're released internationally. Has there
>   ever been an anime which was unpopular with Japanese audiences, and
>   was going to be cancelled or stopped early, but continued or got a
>   sequel purely because of its popularity abroad?

Again, answers should have statements from the staff saying that the series was unlikely to continue until the studio saw the international numbers, or at least some kind of revenue report which strongly suggests that the series makes most of its money abroad. Sakurai Tomoko's comment on the original question claims this is the case with Naruto—that it continues, despite a lack of popularity in Japan, because of its popularity outside Japan.

A related question would be whether there are any cases like what the [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20130620-is-china-hollywoods-future) describes with the movie Battleship—the movie only made $65 million in the US, but made $237 million abroad, more than double what it made in America. We could also ask whether there are any anime which generated disappointing revenues in Japan, but significantly more abroad.

> ### Has any anime had a non-Japanese language track created by the original studio?
>
> Has any anime studio ever made an anime, and also made a dub for it in some language other than Japanese? In particular, has a 
>   non-Japanese dub ever been produced at the same time as the Japanese
>   dub, or even before?

I believe this is true of at least two anime: again, Alexander Senki, and Blood: The Last Vampire. The Animatrix may also once again come into this somewhere.

---

If someone wants to ask any of these questions, you have my blessing. You're also free to take one of the ideas and shape it into your own question.